# how to properly resize navbar fixed in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How to properly change default navbar fixed height in bootstrap 3.
[Here's](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/XaB7r) my snipped. When resize with this css:

```
.navbar-fixed-top{
  height:100px;
}
```

It bricks shrink 
I've also tried

```
.navbar-fixed-top{
  max-height:100px;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do at all. Please clarify your question. See [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: Here's the original snipped http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/XaB7r which works perfect.I just want to resize navbar to another dimension - 100px currently it's 50px when shrinks 40px.But when I add this css it bricks shrink class 
.navbar-fixed-top{
height:100px;
}

Comment: resize is not clear. So I changed it to height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use padding, not a fixed height for the `navbar`. By default it's `min-height: 50px` so once the viewport is under 768px a fixed height will alter the mobile navigation collapse with regard to the background being removed since the `navbar` acts as the background for the links on mobile by expanding.

You'll have to adjust the values to reflect whatever you actually need them to be but this should at least get you started.

See working Snippet.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('nav').addClass('shrink');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
nav {
  transition: all 300ms linear;
}
.navbar.navbar-default {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  padding-top: 5.5px;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand img {
  width: 250px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-brand.navbar-brand-centered {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default > .container .navbar-brand-centered,
  .navbar.navbar-default > .container-fluid .navbar-brand-centered {
    margin-left: -125px;
  }
  nav.navbar.navbar-default.shrink {
    min-height: 35px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  nav.shrink.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-top: -10px;
  }
  nav.shrink.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav a {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  nav.shrink.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    padding: 4px 5px;
    margin: 8px 15px 8px 0;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  nav.navbar.navbar-default.shrink {
    min-height: 35px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  }
  nav.shrink.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    padding-top: 2px;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
  nav.shrink.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    margin-top: 11px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-brand-centered">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered">
        <img src="http://www.sacredpathsoftransformation.com/uploads/7/0/9/7/7097791/_____2174311.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-brand-centered">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-6 col-sm-8">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
      <p>Dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id maxime repellat repellendus porro voluptas laudantium similique eveniet quis perferendis beatae commodi sunt ullam provident dolorum doloribus esse accusamus dolores. Corrupti.</p>
      <p>Consectetur incidunt voluptatibus ipsa nisi esse eos deleniti repudiandae at quo sit praesentium nemo optio perspiciatis sequi quaerat voluptates minus reprehenderit doloremque accusamus et quisquam nesciunt sunt consequatur explicabo excepturi!</p>
      <p>Sequi facilis ea dolor asperiores quibusdam eveniet optio corporis et accusantium voluptatem architecto quis iste recusandae molestias dolorem soluta ex blanditiis illo impedit laborum iusto? Iure sapiente eos molestiae est?</p>
      <p>Numquam delectus recusandae nesciunt rem itaque harum corporis maxime hic iste molestias adipisci excepturi ullam libero necessitatibus cum eum modi minus obcaecati est nemo quia velit earum perferendis consectetur porro?</p>
      <p>Accusamus dicta consequatur quos ipsum rerum tempora assumenda ex excepturi itaque soluta magnam debitis voluptatibus neque eos porro. Neque tempora ea beatae delectus facere quas voluptas accusamus maxime enim consequuntur.</p>
      <p>Saepe obcaecati facilis dolore numquam nam quod laudantium. Rerum esse voluptas eum aut porro beatae adipisci exercitationem ab voluptatum corporis quas placeat sapiente nisi ut officia eaque debitis. Corrupti eveniet!</p>
      <p>Eius natus numquam tempore alias ipsam commodi aut similique corporis beatae velit maxime obcaecati voluptatibus cum repudiandae minus inventore doloremque optio saepe nihil eum reprehenderit quas consequuntur perspiciatis quo quam.</p>
      <p>Ea perspiciatis incidunt unde ipsam cupiditate necessitatibus magnam quod odit. Beatae adipisci non praesentium tenetur dolores fugit repellat consequuntur unde aperiam eligendi ipsa doloribus corporis officiis ipsam quod numquam assumenda!</p>
      <p>Ullam ut ex cum corporis numquam quia hic aut nisi itaque laboriosam eaque earum commodi nulla magni voluptate reiciendis laborum esse odit blanditiis aperiam veniam eos velit similique eveniet ad.</p>
      <p>Esse veritatis inventore explicabo hic consequuntur ex autem praesentium quaerat blanditiis illo deleniti dolorum porro tenetur. Repellat sed repellendus natus cum molestias numquam vitae vel eum voluptatem praesentium tempora quae.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est nostrum consequatur odit eius blanditiis sit mollitia ut porro cumque nam repudiandae accusantium nisi excepturi corporis incidunt inventore ipsam? Officiis eum!</p>
      <p>Nostrum minus dicta quod totam autem ipsum illo velit labore obcaecati est ducimus ullam sit iusto ea pariatur sint nulla perferendis modi dolorum cumque non laboriosam ratione maiores possimus numquam!</p>
      <p>Deserunt ex dolor atque sapiente suscipit aspernatur et iste necessitatibus enim magni blanditiis quaerat rerum perspiciatis expedita magnam nihil neque natus quos quidem veritatis eligendi dolorem itaque laboriosam beatae dolores!</p>
      <p>Nostrum tenetur rem cum tempora sapiente at possimus assumenda ex quos illum facilis quibusdam facere voluptatum. Necessitatibus tempore animi earum inventore quaerat sit velit totam rem nulla consequuntur dolorem architecto!</p>
      <p>Illum doloremque ipsa magni fugiat explicabo nam officiis expedita architecto voluptatem beatae deserunt optio iusto nostrum facere voluptatum. Tempora dolore quasi vero aut voluptatem eaque nobis iusto enim dignissimos molestias!</p>
    </div>
    <!--/.col-xs-12 -->
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-6 col-sm-4">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
      <p>Dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id maxime repellat repellendus porro voluptas laudantium similique eveniet quis perferendis beatae commodi sunt ullam provident dolorum doloribus esse accusamus dolores. Corrupti.</p>
      <p>Consectetur incidunt voluptatibus ipsa nisi esse eos deleniti repudiandae at quo sit praesentium nemo optio perspiciatis sequi quaerat voluptates minus reprehenderit doloremque accusamus et quisquam nesciunt sunt consequatur explicabo excepturi!</p>
      <p>Sequi facilis ea dolor asperiores quibusdam eveniet optio corporis et accusantium voluptatem architecto quis iste recusandae molestias dolorem soluta ex blanditiis illo impedit laborum iusto? Iure sapiente eos molestiae est?</p>
      <p>Numquam delectus recusandae nesciunt rem itaque harum corporis maxime hic iste molestias adipisci excepturi ullam libero necessitatibus cum eum modi minus obcaecati est nemo quia velit earum perferendis consectetur porro?</p>
      <p>Accusamus dicta consequatur quos ipsum rerum tempora assumenda ex excepturi itaque soluta magnam debitis voluptatibus neque eos porro. Neque tempora ea beatae delectus facere quas voluptas accusamus maxime enim consequuntur.</p>
      <p>Saepe obcaecati facilis dolore numquam nam quod laudantium. Rerum esse voluptas eum aut porro beatae adipisci exercitationem ab voluptatum corporis quas placeat sapiente nisi ut officia eaque debitis. Corrupti eveniet!</p>
      <p>Eius natus numquam tempore alias ipsam commodi aut similique corporis beatae velit maxime obcaecati voluptatibus cum repudiandae minus inventore doloremque optio saepe nihil eum reprehenderit quas consequuntur perspiciatis quo quam.</p>
      <p>Ea perspiciatis incidunt unde ipsam cupiditate necessitatibus magnam quod odit. Beatae adipisci non praesentium tenetur dolores fugit repellat consequuntur unde aperiam eligendi ipsa doloribus corporis officiis ipsam quod numquam assumenda!</p>
      <p>Ullam ut ex cum corporis numquam quia hic aut nisi itaque laboriosam eaque earum commodi nulla magni voluptate reiciendis laborum esse odit blanditiis aperiam veniam eos velit similique eveniet ad.</p>
      <p>Esse veritatis inventore explicabo hic consequuntur ex autem praesentium quaerat blanditiis illo deleniti dolorum porro tenetur. Repellat sed repellendus natus cum molestias numquam vitae vel eum voluptatem praesentium tempora quae.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est nostrum consequatur odit eius blanditiis sit mollitia ut porro cumque nam repudiandae accusantium nisi excepturi corporis incidunt inventore ipsam? Officiis eum!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/.row -->
</div>
<!--/.container -->
```

Example 2

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('nav').addClass('shrink');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
nav {
  transition: all 300ms linear;
}
.navbar.navbar-default {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background: black;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand img {
  width: 200px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-brand.navbar-brand-centered {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default > .container .navbar-brand-centered,
  .navbar.navbar-default > .container-fluid .navbar-brand-centered {
    margin-left: -125px;
  }
  nav.shrink.navbar.navbar-default {
    min-height: 35px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  nav.shrink.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-top: -10px;
  }
  nav.shrink.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand img {
    height: 40px;
  }
  nav.shrink.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav a {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  nav.shrink.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    padding: 4px 5px;
    margin: 8px 15px 8px 0;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  nav.navbar.navbar-default.shrink {
    min-height: 35px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  }
  nav.shrink.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    padding-top: 2px;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
  nav.shrink.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand img {
    height: 40px;
  }
  nav.shrink.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    margin-top: 11px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-brand-centered">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered">
        <img src="http://eventswork.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/250x100.png" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-brand-centered">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-6 col-sm-8">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
      <p>Dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id maxime repellat repellendus porro voluptas laudantium similique eveniet quis perferendis beatae commodi sunt ullam provident dolorum doloribus esse accusamus dolores. Corrupti.</p>
      <p>Consectetur incidunt voluptatibus ipsa nisi esse eos deleniti repudiandae at quo sit praesentium nemo optio perspiciatis sequi quaerat voluptates minus reprehenderit doloremque accusamus et quisquam nesciunt sunt consequatur explicabo excepturi!</p>
      <p>Sequi facilis ea dolor asperiores quibusdam eveniet optio corporis et accusantium voluptatem architecto quis iste recusandae molestias dolorem soluta ex blanditiis illo impedit laborum iusto? Iure sapiente eos molestiae est?</p>
      <p>Numquam delectus recusandae nesciunt rem itaque harum corporis maxime hic iste molestias adipisci excepturi ullam libero necessitatibus cum eum modi minus obcaecati est nemo quia velit earum perferendis consectetur porro?</p>
      <p>Accusamus dicta consequatur quos ipsum rerum tempora assumenda ex excepturi itaque soluta magnam debitis voluptatibus neque eos porro. Neque tempora ea beatae delectus facere quas voluptas accusamus maxime enim consequuntur.</p>
      <p>Saepe obcaecati facilis dolore numquam nam quod laudantium. Rerum esse voluptas eum aut porro beatae adipisci exercitationem ab voluptatum corporis quas placeat sapiente nisi ut officia eaque debitis. Corrupti eveniet!</p>
      <p>Eius natus numquam tempore alias ipsam commodi aut similique corporis beatae velit maxime obcaecati voluptatibus cum repudiandae minus inventore doloremque optio saepe nihil eum reprehenderit quas consequuntur perspiciatis quo quam.</p>
      <p>Ea perspiciatis incidunt unde ipsam cupiditate necessitatibus magnam quod odit. Beatae adipisci non praesentium tenetur dolores fugit repellat consequuntur unde aperiam eligendi ipsa doloribus corporis officiis ipsam quod numquam assumenda!</p>
      <p>Ullam ut ex cum corporis numquam quia hic aut nisi itaque laboriosam eaque earum commodi nulla magni voluptate reiciendis laborum esse odit blanditiis aperiam veniam eos velit similique eveniet ad.</p>
      <p>Esse veritatis inventore explicabo hic consequuntur ex autem praesentium quaerat blanditiis illo deleniti dolorum porro tenetur. Repellat sed repellendus natus cum molestias numquam vitae vel eum voluptatem praesentium tempora quae.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est nostrum consequatur odit eius blanditiis sit mollitia ut porro cumque nam repudiandae accusantium nisi excepturi corporis incidunt inventore ipsam? Officiis eum!</p>
      <p>Nostrum minus dicta quod totam autem ipsum illo velit labore obcaecati est ducimus ullam sit iusto ea pariatur sint nulla perferendis modi dolorum cumque non laboriosam ratione maiores possimus numquam!</p>
      <p>Deserunt ex dolor atque sapiente suscipit aspernatur et iste necessitatibus enim magni blanditiis quaerat rerum perspiciatis expedita magnam nihil neque natus quos quidem veritatis eligendi dolorem itaque laboriosam beatae dolores!</p>
      <p>Nostrum tenetur rem cum tempora sapiente at possimus assumenda ex quos illum facilis quibusdam facere voluptatum. Necessitatibus tempore animi earum inventore quaerat sit velit totam rem nulla consequuntur dolorem architecto!</p>
      <p>Illum doloremque ipsa magni fugiat explicabo nam officiis expedita architecto voluptatem beatae deserunt optio iusto nostrum facere voluptatum. Tempora dolore quasi vero aut voluptatem eaque nobis iusto enim dignissimos molestias!</p>
    </div>
    <!--/.col-xs-12 -->
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-6 col-sm-4">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
      <p>Dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id maxime repellat repellendus porro voluptas laudantium similique eveniet quis perferendis beatae commodi sunt ullam provident dolorum doloribus esse accusamus dolores. Corrupti.</p>
      <p>Consectetur incidunt voluptatibus ipsa nisi esse eos deleniti repudiandae at quo sit praesentium nemo optio perspiciatis sequi quaerat voluptates minus reprehenderit doloremque accusamus et quisquam nesciunt sunt consequatur explicabo excepturi!</p>
      <p>Sequi facilis ea dolor asperiores quibusdam eveniet optio corporis et accusantium voluptatem architecto quis iste recusandae molestias dolorem soluta ex blanditiis illo impedit laborum iusto? Iure sapiente eos molestiae est?</p>
      <p>Numquam delectus recusandae nesciunt rem itaque harum corporis maxime hic iste molestias adipisci excepturi ullam libero necessitatibus cum eum modi minus obcaecati est nemo quia velit earum perferendis consectetur porro?</p>
      <p>Accusamus dicta consequatur quos ipsum rerum tempora assumenda ex excepturi itaque soluta magnam debitis voluptatibus neque eos porro. Neque tempora ea beatae delectus facere quas voluptas accusamus maxime enim consequuntur.</p>
      <p>Saepe obcaecati facilis dolore numquam nam quod laudantium. Rerum esse voluptas eum aut porro beatae adipisci exercitationem ab voluptatum corporis quas placeat sapiente nisi ut officia eaque debitis. Corrupti eveniet!</p>
      <p>Eius natus numquam tempore alias ipsam commodi aut similique corporis beatae velit maxime obcaecati voluptatibus cum repudiandae minus inventore doloremque optio saepe nihil eum reprehenderit quas consequuntur perspiciatis quo quam.</p>
      <p>Ea perspiciatis incidunt unde ipsam cupiditate necessitatibus magnam quod odit. Beatae adipisci non praesentium tenetur dolores fugit repellat consequuntur unde aperiam eligendi ipsa doloribus corporis officiis ipsam quod numquam assumenda!</p>
      <p>Ullam ut ex cum corporis numquam quia hic aut nisi itaque laboriosam eaque earum commodi nulla magni voluptate reiciendis laborum esse odit blanditiis aperiam veniam eos velit similique eveniet ad.</p>
      <p>Esse veritatis inventore explicabo hic consequuntur ex autem praesentium quaerat blanditiis illo deleniti dolorum porro tenetur. Repellat sed repellendus natus cum molestias numquam vitae vel eum voluptatem praesentium tempora quae.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est nostrum consequatur odit eius blanditiis sit mollitia ut porro cumque nam repudiandae accusantium nisi excepturi corporis incidunt inventore ipsam? Officiis eum!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/.row -->
</div>
<!--/.container -->
```

Comment: Yes you're right!
Before that I've tried with this css but bricks on mobile view:
.navbar-fixed-top {
    min-height: 80px;
}

.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse {
    max-height: 80px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse {
        max-height: 50px;
    }
}

Comment: Ok but if my image is with another size - updated snipped - http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/XaB7r

Comment: Like I stated in the original answer, you'll have to change the values to reflect whatever the image size is and what you want it to be when it's reduced. See updated answer, Example 2.

Comment: Thanks I understand! :)
How to center image when going to mobile size ?